# Breaking Child Data Into Multiple records based on Parent ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement where i need to break child data into multiple records .Below,im trying to make you understand with some sample date
as i should not post original data . In the below data for every ParentId we may have multiple child records.So,now
**we need to display every record with 3 child's data in separate columns along with their corresponding Parent Id** as shown in below expected output.
We have tried with  cursors even though we got but it it is killing the execution time and also we have thought of using pivot and seems like it become much complex and i'm not sure it may work .
Any help or approach will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Parent Table

```
SELECT * into  #Parent FROM (
SELECT 1 PARENTID,'A' PARENTNAME
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'D'
) AS A
```

Child Table

```
SELECT * INTO #Child from (
SELECT 10 as CHILDID,1 as PARENTID ,'DEF' AS CHILDNAME
union all
SELECT 11 , 1,'EFG'
UNION ALL
SELECT 12,1,'GHI'
UNION ALL
SELECT 13,1,'JKL'
UNION ALL
SELECT 14,1,'MNO'
UNION ALL
SELECT 15,1,'PQR'
UNION ALL
SELECT 20,2,'ACE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 30,3,'STU'
UNION ALL
SELECT 31,3,'VWX'
UNION ALL
SELECT 32,3,'WXY'
UNION ALL
SELECT 33,3,'XYZ'
)as a

SELECT * FROM #Parent
SELECT * FROM #CHILD
```

Expected Result:

```
PARENTID Child1Name Child2Name Child3Name
1            DEF      EFG        GHI
1            JKL      MNO        PQR
2            ACE      NULL       NULL
3            STU      VWX        WXY
3            XYZ      NULL       NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate the two row_numbers using `row_number()` function no need for cursor

```
SELECT 
    p.PARENTID,
    coalesce(max(case when c.rn1=1 then c.ChildName end), max(case when c.rn1%3=1 then c.ChildName end)) [Child1Name],
    coalesce(max(case when c.rn1=2 then c.ChildName end), max(case when c.rn1%3=2 then c.ChildName end)) [Child2Name],
    coalesce(max(case when c.rn1=3 then c.ChildName end), max(case when c.rn1%3=0 then c.ChildName end)) [Child3Name]
    FROM Parent p 
join
(SELECT *, (row_number() over (partition by PARENTID order by childid)-1)/3 rn,
           row_number() over (partition by PARENTID order by childid) rn1 FROM CHILD) c on c.PARENTID = p.PARENTID
group by p.PARENTID, c.rn 
order by p.PARENTID
```

Result :

```
PARENTID Child1Name Child2Name Child3Name
1            DEF      EFG        GHI
1            JKL      MNO        PQR
2            ACE      NULL       NULL
3            STU      VWX        WXY
3            XYZ      NULL       NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NTILE` & `ROW_NUMBER`for deviding them into group of 3 records

```
SELECT PARENTID,CHILD1, CHILD2,CHILD3 FROM (
SELECT 'CHILD'+CASE WHEN grp='0' THEN '3' ELSE grp END CHILDS
,CAST(NTILE(2) OVER(PARTITION BY PARENTID ORDER BY CHILDID) AS VARCHAR(10))
+'-' +CAST(PARENTID AS VARCHAR(10)) as PARENTID_2
,  PARENTID, CHILDNAME FROM (
SELECT  CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PARENTID ORDER BY CHILDID)%3 AS VARCHAR(10)) 
 AS grp
,* FROM #CHILD 
)A
)B
PIVOT
(
    MAX(CHILDNAME) FOR CHILDS IN([CHILD1],[CHILD2],[CHILD3])
)PV
```

**Result:**

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
| PARENTID | CHILD1 | CHILD2 | CHILD3 |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|        1 | DEF    | EFG    | GHI    |
|        1 | JKL    | MNO    | PQR    |
|        2 | ACE    | NULL   | NULL   |
|        3 | STU    | VWX    | NULL   |
|        3 | XYZ    | NULL   | WXY    |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Please revise "*result*" section, it's a little different from OP Mahesh's and Yogesh's.

Comment: Yeah.. Seen. For that only I've upvoted both of you. @KtX2SkD

Answer (score 1):

**Major rewrite of original answer**, you just need one `PIVOT`, two `ROW_NUMBER`, and that's all:

```
SELECT PARENTID, [0], [1], [2]
FROM (
    SELECT
        PARENTID
      , CHILDNAME
      , ParentBreaker = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PARENTID ORDER BY CHILDID) - 1) / 3 + 1 -- You want this to facilitate splitting every 3 child records.
      , Child#Name = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PARENTID ORDER BY CHILDID) - 1) % 3
    FROM #Child 
) AS RowNumbered
PIVOT (
    MAX(CHILDNAME)
    FOR Child#Name IN ([0], [1], [2])
) AS T
ORDER BY PARENTID
```

With a quick `CONCAT` and a +1 on `Child#Name`, you can probably simulate the column names in your "*expected result*" as well.

Comment: In original answer, apparently `#CHILD_2` and `#FINAL_RESULT` were identical, which ensued finding out severe redundancy in the logic, if that's the word.